# My imported Character from Daz 3d appears black when rendered in cycles, but the materials are normal in look-dev mode

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I imported a character I designed in Daz 3d and when It came already Uv unwrapped, but when I add image textures from polygon onto the character it appears in look dev mode perfectly fine.

[image]

However when in render mode it appears completely black even with the light intensity maxxed out. Help please I'm very new to blender and have been trying to figure this out for days

[image]

Comment: Are there lights in the scene? and are they string enough?

Comment: yes  I put the light directly in front of the characters face with the size to .5 to accurately test it, but at most there are little shiny spots but its almost completely black

Comment: Increase the power to some large number and try

Comment: unfortunately that also doesn't seem to work, even with the wattage at 5000 for the light, could it be an issue with the nodes?

Comment: Is there any duplicate mesh that is fighting the one you are looking at, and do your mesh normals point outward?

Comment: Please attach simplified blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to let us check your setup. Thank you

Comment: Go into Blender Modifier and select Subdivision surface and it will work. Thanks